# Redis keyspace notifications with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I've looking around and I'm unable to find how to perform a subscription to keyspace notifications on Redis using StackExchange.Redis library.

Checking available tests I've found pubsub using channels, but this is more to work like a service bus/queueing rather than subscribing to specific Redis key events.

***Is it possible to take advantage of this Redis feature using StackExchange.Redis?***

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The regular subscriber API should work fine - there is no assumption on use-cases, and this should work fine.

However, I do kinda agree that this is inbuilt functionality that could perhaps benefit from helper methods on the API, and perhaps a different delegate signature - to encapsulate the syntax of the keyapace notifications so that people don't need to duplicate it. For that: I suggest you log an issue so that it doesn't get forgotten.

### Simple sample of how to subscribe to a keyspace event

First of all, it's important to check that Redis keyspace events are enabled. For example, events should be enabled on keys of type *Set*. This can be done using `CONFIG SET` command:

```
CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEs
```

Once keyspace events are enabled, it's just about subscribing to the pub-sub channel:

```
using (ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost"))
{
    IDatabase db = connection.GetDatabase();
    ISubscriber subscriber = connection.GetSubscriber();

    subscriber.Subscribe("__keyspace@0__:*", (channel, value) =>
        {
            if ((string)channel == "__keyspace@0__:users" && (string)value == "sadd")
            {
                // Do stuff if some item is added to a hypothethical "users" set in Redis
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Learn more about keyspace events [here](http://redis.io/topics/notifications).

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend what the selected answer already describes:

```
using (ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost"))
{
    IDatabase db = connection.GetDatabase();
    ISubscriber subscriber = connection.GetSubscriber();

    subscriber.Subscribe($"__keyspace@0__:{channel}", (channel, value) =>
        {
          // Do whatever channel specific handling you need to do here, in my case I used exact Key name that I wanted expiration event for.  
        }
    );
}
```

Another important thing, I had to subscribe KEx (CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events **KEx**
) to get channel based updates for expiration notifications.