# Expiration callback in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, callback, redis, stackexchange.redis

Does StackExchange.Redis has any ability to execute callback after cache item was expired?
Like ICacheItemRefreshAction in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching

```
    [Serializable]
    private class CacheEventHandler : ICacheItemRefreshAction
    {
        public void Refresh(string key, object expiredValue, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason)
        {
            // Item has been removed from cache. Perform desired actions here, based upon
            // the removal reason (e.g. refresh the cache with the item).
            ResetStaticData();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't ever possible (or it might be very unreliable), because *Redis* has some limitations on its built-in keyspace events when it comes to raising an event when a key expires ([learn more here](http://redis.io/topics/notifications)):

> Timing of expired events
>
> Keys with a time to live associated are expired by Redis in two ways:
>
> - When the key is accessed by a command and is found to be expired.
> - Via a background system that looks for expired keys in background, incrementally, in order to be able to also collect keys that are never
>     accessed.

Thus, what you want isn't reliable at all. What happens if you want to re-introduce data after some cached key has expired but *Redis* tells you that the so-called key has expired so late?

In the other hand, *Redis* keyspace notifications are implemented using regular *pubsub* channels, and *Redis* pubsub is implemented over the concept of *fire-and-forget*. What happens if the process listening for key expirations isn't working when *Redis* wants to notify it?

I suggest you that you may better solve the issue using a task scheduler rather than relying on *Redis* for this.

### When to rely on built-in expiration system

Even when you can't rely on notifications about key expirations, I would say that built-in expiration system is very powerful.

A sample use case might be that you need to expose a set of data to your users, and these users access to that data set a lot of times per hour.

That is, you add the so-called data set to *Redis* and you put an expiration time of 2 hours, and since the whole data doesn't change very much, your users won't access to the primary data while the data is cached in *Redis*.

After the data has expired, until not a great number of users access the data, *Redis* has no cache for it.

There're a lot of use cases for the `expire` command, but again, I would say that it's not good to take actions in real-time based on cache expiration.

### If you want to go this route anyway...

...check a Q&A I openen a long time ago where you'll find a sample code about how to subscribe to keyspace pubsub channels:

- [Redis keyspace notifications with StackExchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180765/redis-keyspace-notifications-with-stackexchange-redis)